# LaTeX: Shadowed text within colorbox with border line on right and bottom

Tags: xetex

I would like to build the following structure within LaTeX: 
[image]

The font is Arial with type bold. For now I was able to build the following with TeX:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathrm{Arial}
\setmathsf{Arial}
\setmathtt{Arial}
\usepackage{shadowtext, color}

\begin{document}
    %
    Hier steht etwas ...\\

   \definecolor{bkg}{rgb}{.843,.882,.98}
   \definecolor{navy}{rgb}{.294,.513,.784}

   \colorbox{bkg}{\parbox[c][152pt]{.5\textwidth}{
       % 
       \quad \qquad           
       \shadowrgb{.541, .568, .631}
       \shadowoffset{2.5pt}
       \shadowtext{
           \color{navy}
           %\fontencoding{T1}%
           %\fontfamily{pag}%
           \fontseries{b}%
           \fontsize{128}{128}\selectfont
           01
       }
   }}

\end{document}
```

With the result:

[image]

My issues are:

1. Text within the colorbox does not look as the original one, despite both should be Arial with type bold.
2. The shadow of the LaTeX version does not look like the shadow of the original

Maybe anyone has any idea how I could achive that the TeX build text look like the original text build with Word.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are right! Please could anyone move this to the correct site?

Comment: I have already flagged the question, I guess it's a matter of time until it is reviewed and moved

Comment: Welcome! If you use XeLaTeX to compile your document (which I assume from the `xetex` tag), you should not use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, 
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}`. In fact you already use `fontspec` and load Arial as main font. Furthermore, you should consider using `\bfseries` instead of `\fontseries{b}`, which should solve your first issue.

As for your second issue, I am very sorry to have to tell you that, at least as far as I know, there is no feasable way to attach a blurred shadow to text with TeX (only to shapes with the `pgf-blur` package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of the `pst-blur` package. In order to be able to use this package on glyphs, the glyphs first have to be outlined. As all this cannot easily be done using a simple run of PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could put the code for the box in a separate .tex file and then include the result via `\includegraphics`. The following code should be compiled with LaTeX, dvips and ps2pdf.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-text,pst-blur,xcolor,etoolbox}
\definecolor{bkg}{rgb}{.843,.882,.98}
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{.294,.513,.784}

\begin{document}%
 \psset{unit=1pt}%
 \DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{50mm}%
 \begin{pspicture}(-20,-25)(20,125)%
  \begin{psclip}{\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bkg,linestyle=none](-20,-25)(180,125)}%
   \pscharpath[shadow=true,blur=true,blurbg=bkg,linestyle=none,fillcolor=navy]{\RM 01}%
  \end{psclip}%
 \end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

Yields:

[image]

---

**Edit: overkill solution of which the result can possibly achieved with less effort**

main.tex (to be compiled with PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX using `--shell-escape`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\numberinbox}[1]{
 \newwrite\boxfile
 \immediate\openout\boxfile=theboxnumber.aux\relax
 \immediate\write\boxfile{#1}%
 \immediate\closeout\boxfile

 \def\currentnumber{#1}
 \immediate\write18{latex thebox.tex}
 \immediate\write18{dvips -o thebox.ps thebox.dvi}
 \immediate\write18{ps2pdf thebox.ps thebox\currentnumber.pdf}

 \includegraphics{thebox\currentnumber.pdf}
} 

\begin{document}

Some other text ...

\numberinbox{02}

\numberinbox{03} 

\end{document}
```

thebox.tex (to be put into the working directory):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-text,pst-blur,xcolor,etoolbox}
\definecolor{bkg}{rgb}{.843,.882,.98}
\definecolor{navy}{rgb}{.294,.513,.784}

\newread\boxfile
\openin\boxfile=theboxnumber.aux\relax
\read\boxfile to\thenumber
\closein\boxfile

\begin{document}%
 \psset{unit=1pt}%
 \DeclareFixedFont{\RM}{T1}{phv}{b}{n}{50mm}%
 \begin{pspicture}(-20,-25)(20,125)%
  \begin{psclip}{\psframe[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=bkg,linestyle=none](-20,-25)(180,125)}%
   \pscharpath[shadow=true,blur=true,blurbg=bkg,linestyle=none,fillcolor=navy]{\RM\thenumber}%
  \end{psclip}%
 \end{pspicture}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the output, you see that your code produced the complaint

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `TU/Arial(0)/b/n' undefined
(Font)              using `TU/Arial(0)/m/n' instead on input line 34.
```

So you need to replace `\fontseries{b}` by `\fontseries{bx}` to obtain

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{translator}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\setmathrm{Arial}
\setmathsf{Arial}
\setmathtt{Arial}
\usepackage{shadowtext, color}

\begin{document}
    %
    Hier steht etwas von einem Murmeltier...\\

   \definecolor{bkg}{rgb}{.843,.882,.98}
   \definecolor{navy}{rgb}{.294,.513,.784}

   \colorbox{bkg}{\parbox[c][152pt]{.5\textwidth}{
       % 
       \quad \qquad           
       \shadowrgb{.541, .568, .631}
       \shadowoffset{2.5pt}
       \shadowtext{
           \color{navy}
           %\fontencoding{T1}%
           %\fontfamily{pag}%
           \fontseries{bx}%
           \fontsize{128}{128}\selectfont
           01
       }
   }}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this only solves my first issue. Therefore I gave an acceptance to Jasper's response.